# getting Run crashed when i run the Karate gatling with Gradle

Tags: gradle, karate

```js
package mock

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class CatsKarateSimulation extends Simulation {

  MockUtils.startServer()

  val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("catName" -> MockUtils.getNextCatName))

  val protocol = karateProtocol(
    "/cats/{id}" -> Nil,
    "/cats" -> pauseFor("get" -> 15, "post" -> 25)
  )

  protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

  val create = scenario("create").feed(feeder).exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-create.feature"))
  val delete = scenario("delete").group("delete cats") {
    exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-delete.feature@name=delete"))
  }
  val custom = scenario("custom").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/custom-rpc.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    delete.inject(rampUsers(5) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    custom.inject(rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )

}
```

Can anyone help why I am getting this error:
Currently my project has karate api scripts and there are few java helper classes in it, i need to implement the Gatling with gradle.
Java: 11
Gradle: Gradle 7.5.1
Windows 10
Eclipse IDE

1. build.gradle
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teC71.png)
2. Simulation
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcx7d.png)
3. Folder structure
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQFG7.png)
4. Error

   `15:50:51.523 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User defined Simulation class mock.CatsKarateSimulation could not be loaded at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.findUserDefinedSimulationInClassloader$1(Selection.scala:87) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$4(Selection.scala:91) at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$3(Selection.scala:91) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.singleSimulationFromConfig(Selection.scala:90) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$selection$1(Selection.scala:52) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.selection(Selection.scala:44) at io.gatling.app.Selection$.apply(Selection.scala:36) at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:61) at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:49) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:87) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38) at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mock.CatsKarateSimulation at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$2(Selection.scala:76) at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.findUserDefinedSimulationInClassloader$1(Selection.scala:76) ... 15 common frames omitted Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User defined Simulation class mock.CatsKarateSimulation could not be loaded at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.findUserDefinedSimulationInClassloader$1(Selection.scala:87) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$4(Selection.scala:91) at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$3(Selection.scala:91) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.singleSimulationFromConfig(Selection.scala:90) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$selection$1(Selection.scala:52) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.selection(Selection.scala:44) at io.gatling.app.Selection$.apply(Selection.scala:36) at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:61) at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:49) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:87) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49) at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38) at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mock.CatsKarateSimulation at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$2(Selection.scala:76) at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210) at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.findUserDefinedSimulationInClassloader$1(Selection.scala:76)`

Comment: please see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gatling+run+crashed - if you really want more help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue